# Failure adding filter to pipeline in gstreamer

Tags: c, video, media, gstreamer, pipeline

I'm trying to do the exercise at the end of the Basic GStreamer tutorial here: [Basic Tutorial 2](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Basic+tutorial+2%3a+GStreamer+concepts). The exercise is merely to add a filter to a video. The exercise says to simply add the "vertigoTV" effect, so I did that.

Here are the relevant parts to my attempt:

```
    #include <gst/gst.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GstElement *pipeline, *source, *filter, *convert, *sink;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;
  GstStateChangeReturn ret;

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Create the elements */
  source = gst_element_factory_make ("videotestsrc", "source");
  filter = gst_element_factory_make ("vertigotv", "filter");
  sink = gst_element_factory_make ("autovideosink", "sink");

  /* Create the empty pipeline */
  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline");

  if (!pipeline || !source || !filter || !sink) {
    g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  /* Build the pipeline */
  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, filter, sink, NULL);
  if (gst_element_link_many (source, filter, sink, NULL) != TRUE) {
    g_printerr ("Could not link all elements.\n");
    gst_object_unref (pipeline);
    return -1;
  }

  /* Modify the source's properties */
  g_object_set (source, "pattern", 0, NULL);

  /* Start playing */
  ret = gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
    g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
    gst_object_unref (pipeline);
    return -1;
  }

  /* Wait until error or EOS */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
  msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

  /* Parse message */
  if (msg != NULL) {
    GError *err;
    gchar *debug_info;

    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
      case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
        gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &debug_info);
        g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
        g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
        g_clear_error (&err);
        g_free (debug_info);
        break;
      case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
        g_print ("End-Of-Stream reached.\n");
        break;
      default:
        /* We should not reach here because we only asked for ERRORs and EOS */
        g_printerr ("Unexpected message received.\n");
        break;
    }
    gst_message_unref (msg);
  }

  /* Free resources */
  gst_object_unref (bus);
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  return 0;
}
```

However, the return value is a GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE. Any idea why?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Check if the filter element has been created properly. Add the code if(!filter)  g_printerr ("Filter failed"); and see what happens.

Comment: The element is created properly. I've edited the OP to show the entire code I'm using, including that check you mentioned.

Comment: Ran your code, works fine for me. What is the full error message you're getting?

Comment: The full error is simply "Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state", from the code where I set the pipeline to a playing state. That's frustrating that it works fine for you. I can only assume it is a system specific issue. I'm on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Try it on the command line: type gst-launch-0.10 videotestsrc ! vertigotv ! autovideosink and see what happens.

Comment: Huh, seems like it was some sort of issue with the imaage format. I got it working  now by adding a "ffmpegcolorspace" after the vertigo filter. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a videoconvert after the filter as well:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! vertigotv ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

Comment: I couldn't add a videoconvert element to my code... the element refuses to be created. Any idea why? Is "videoconvert" only for the command version of the program?

Comment: Turns out I needed to use a "ffmpegcolorspace" converter instead of the "videoconvert" converter. Now it works... thanks so much!

Comment: Yes in 0.10 it was called ffmpegcolorspace.

Answer (score 1):

This will definitely work, I have tried and got it working.

Please try some other steps or add the exact error you got.
You may also want to post the complete code.

P.S - wanted to add this as comment but fall short of 2 rep

Comment: I probably should have just put the entire code. I've edited the OP. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#endif

int tutorial_main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GstElement *pipeline, *source, *sink, *filter, *converter;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;
  GstStateChangeReturn ret;

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init(&argc, &argv);

  /* Create the elements */
  source = gst_element_factory_make("videotestsrc", "source");
  filter = gst_element_factory_make("vertigotv", "filter");
  converter = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "converter");
  sink = gst_element_factory_make("autovideosink", "sink");

  /* Create the empty pipeline */
  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("test-pipeline");

  if (!pipeline || !source || !filter || !converter || !sink)
  {
    g_printerr("Not all elements could be created.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  /* Build the pipeline */
  gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), source, filter, converter, sink, NULL);
  // if (gst_element_link(source, sink) != TRUE)
  // {
  //   g_printerr("Elements could not be linked.\n");
  //   gst_object_unref(pipeline);
  //   return -1;
  // }
  if (gst_element_link_many(source, filter, converter, sink, NULL) != TRUE)
  {
      g_printerr("Elements could not be linked.\n");
      gst_object_unref(pipeline);
      return -1;
  }
  /* Modify the source's properties */
  g_object_set(source, "pattern", 0, NULL);

  /* Start playing */
  ret = gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE)
  {
    g_printerr("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
    gst_object_unref(pipeline);
    return -1;
  }

  /* Wait until error or EOS */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus(pipeline);
  msg =
      gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
                                 GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

  /* Parse message */
  if (msg != NULL)
  {
    GError *err;
    gchar *debug_info;

    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(msg))
    {
    case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
      gst_message_parse_error(msg, &err, &debug_info);
      g_printerr("Error received from element %s: %s\n",
                 GST_OBJECT_NAME(msg->src), err->message);
      g_printerr("Debugging information: %s\n",
                 debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
      g_clear_error(&err);
      g_free(debug_info);
      break;
    case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
      g_print("End-Of-Stream reached.\n");
      break;
    default:
      /* We should not reach here because we only asked for ERRORs and EOS */
      g_printerr("Unexpected message received.\n");
      break;
    }
    gst_message_unref(msg);
  }

  /* Free resources */
  gst_object_unref(bus);
  gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref(pipeline);
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if defined(__APPLE__) && TARGET_OS_MAC && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE
  return gst_macos_main(tutorial_main, argc, argv, NULL);
#else
  return tutorial_main(argc, argv);
#endif
}
```

Comment: This code generates same output as  this gst command does with  vertigotv filter .

gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! vertigotv ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).